# Character Encoding Issue in XML

Tags: character-encoding

This word is causing me problems. Brúðkaup

In my cms, at the top of the webpage I have this line.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

The database stores the word above as `BrÃºÃ°kaup` and has a charset of `latin1`

At the top of my xml file I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Is the database using the wrong character encoding? Even if it is. Why is it that in html I specify the utf8 charset and the word shows correctly. Yet in XML I do something similar and it doesn't?

The XML is generated by PHP. I have tried to add the following in my script.

```
header('charset=utf-8');
```

This doesn't make any difference. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is latin1 (= ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252) encoded, it needs to be converted to UTF-8 in order to be displayed on a page in UTF-8 encoding. The tools for this depend on the software you use to get data from the database and put it into an HTML or XML document.

If the HTML file shows correctly, then either such a conversion was made at some point, or the HTML file is actually interpreted, by a browser, as latin1 encoded. This would happen if the server sends HTTP Content-Type header that specifies charset parameter to that effect – HTTP headers override `meta` tags.